# How to keep the buffer of std::cin after using std::cin.getline()

Tags: c++, std, cin, istream

I am trying to re-read the cin buffer after using cin.getline() 5 times, by calling cin.seekg(), but after calling cin.getline() again, instead of re-reading the data from the top, str becomes an empty string. Does cin.getline() flush the buffer? If so how do I stop that from happening?

```
#define PATH_MAX 512
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    char* str = new char[PATH_MAX + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cin.getline(str, PATH_MAX);

    cin.seekg(cin.beg);

    while(true)
        cin.getline(str, PATH_MAX);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `seekg` ends up calling [`streambuf::seekpos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubseekpos): "The base class version of this function has no effect. The derived classes may override this function to allow absolute positioning of the position indicator." Classes like `filebuf` and `stringbuf` override it and do something useful, but `cin` isn't using one of those. Bottom line: you cannot seek on `cin`. If you want to look at the data a second time, read it and store it somewhere.

Comment: `cin.seekg(cin.beg);` is incorrect, it should just be `cin.seekg(0);`, but most likely is that `std::cin` simply isn't seekable. There's no requirement that it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to re-read the `cin` buffer after using `cin.getline()` 5 times

That's not possible with `cin`, terminal based input respectively.

What you can do is keeping track of the read input yourself, using a `std::vector<std::string>` keeping those lines read in 1st place. Here's a rough sketch:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>    
using std::cin;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    std::vector<string> lines;
    string line;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::getline(cin,line);
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    auto linepos = lines.begin();
    while(linepos != lines.end()) {
        // cin.getline(str, PATH_MAX); instead do:
        // process *linepos
        ++linepos;
    }
}
```